# User's Permission Database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, permissions, database

Whenever any user creates a SharePoint site , in which database site-title and user permissions are stored in SQL server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint store everything in the content database. In each content database there are many tables, which hold the information.

Let's say you have **site collection A** in **content DB 01**,  So when user creates site under a **site collection A** it store all the information from content to security in the **Content DB 01**. For specifically the user permission related.

**Groups**: Table that holds information about all the SharePoint groups in each site collection.

**Roles**:Table that holds information about all the SharePoint roles (permission levels) for each site.

**GroupMembership**: Table that holds information about all the SharePoint group members.

**RoleAssignment**"Table that holds information about all the users or SharePoint groups that are assigned to roles.

Here is great blog on technet epxlains important table in a content DB. [Inside a SharePoint Content DB](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2010/12/20/inside-a-sharepoint-content-db/)